# d3.js - Time scale with ticks in milliseconds

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I need to plot a line graph where x-axis will have ticks representing time with milliseconds detail.

For x-scale, I am using `d3.time.scale()`

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width])
```

x-axis looks like:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)   
    //.ticks(d3.time.second, 1)
    .orient("bottom")        
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M %L"));
```

But values/ticks on x-axis are not generating as expected.

[image: x-axis with time scale]

data for x-axis are date objects and they hold following values(sample data)

```
13:25:6 794 (%H:%M%S %L)
13:25:6 898 
13:25:6 994 
13:25:7 95 
13:25:7 194 
13:25:7 295 
13:25:7 395 
13:25:7 495 
13:25:7 595 
13:25:7 710 
13:25:7 795 
13:25:7 895
13:25:7 995 
13:25:8 95 
13:25:8 195 
13:25:8 294
13:25:8 395 
13:25:8 495
13:25:8 594
13:25:8 795
```

However if I take linear scale `d3.scale.linear()`
Ticks generated follow a expected series.

[image: x-axis with linear scale]

whats the correct way of using `time scale` with data having millisecond details.

***How can I have tick intervals in seconds:milliseconds?***

**EDIT:**

Also, how can I have ticks every few milliseconds say every 500 ms?

there is an API `d3.time.second` but nothing like `d3.time.millisecond`. How can I add one?

[**Fiddle** using time scale](http://jsfiddle.net/SGyQN/)

Comment: Do you need 13:25:6 794 format in the x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Removed outdated previous answer)

I created an issue for this against the d3 project and it has been fixed: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1529

An example can be seen here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6618724

Comment: thnx Eric. `"javascript Date objects have resolution down to the millisecond, their representation often doesn't include this."` I had a same guess. But I thought there must be a way and someone must have done what i was looking for, so i dint go and posted the issue on `git:mbostock/d3`

Answer (score 4):

intervals in seconds:milliseconds means, you can try out this

```
.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%S %L"));
```

Comment: :D well i did try that. `.ticks(d3.time.second, 0.2)` the line is commented out, as in the question. It dint do the job. I was expecting more ticks to be plotted. but could only see 2 ticks. `13:25:07 000    13:25:08 000`